# Relating distance between two points to the distance between their images under a linear map

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $T:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ be an invertible linear map, let $P\subseteq \mathbb R^n$, and let $\vec x\in \mathbb R^n\backslash P$. Suppose that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, $B_{\varepsilon}(T(\vec x))$ intersects $T(P)$. Does it follow that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, $B_{\varepsilon}(\vec x)$ intersects $P$?

I can find a point $T(\vec y)\in T(P)$ that's arbitrarily close to $T(\vec x)$, and I want to use this to upper bound the distance between $\vec x$ and $\vec y$. But the only way I can think to relate the distance between $T(\vec x)$ and $T(\vec y)$ with the distance between $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ is by

$$|T(\vec x) - T(\vec y)| \leq |T||\vec x - \vec y|$$

and I don't see how to get an upper bound for $|\vec x - \vec y|$ in terms of $|T(\vec x) - T(\vec y)|$ out of this.

Note: $B_\varepsilon(\vec v)$ is the open ball of radius $\varepsilon$ centered at $\vec v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly get an upper bound on |x->-y->| from |T(x->)-T(y->)|. However, since T is invertible, you can apply T^-1 to both sides of the inequality to get:

|T^-1(T(x->)-T(y->))| <= |T^-1||x->-y->|
Since T^-1(T(x->)-T(y->)) = x->-y->, this gives you the upper bound you want:
|x->-y->| <= |T^-1||x->-y->|